# Plyr changing class from numeric to character

Tags: r, plyr

When I try using `ddply` to summarize some aspect of a data.frame, if I only include expressions that result in numeric data, things are fine. However, if I include expressions that result in both numeric and character data, all the output columns become character, which I decidedly did NOT anticipate and really mucked up my code downstream. Here's a reproducible example of what I'm talking about:

```
library(plyr)
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(x = 1:25,
                   y = c((1:25)*4 + rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 50),
                         (1:25)*4 + rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1000)),
                   category = c(rep("stuff with a stronger correlation", 100),
                                rep("stuff with a weaker correlation", 100)))

lmresults <- ddply(data, "category", function(df) c(
      slope = coef(lm(df$y ~ df$x))[2],
      pval = signif(summary(lm(df$y ~ df$x))$coef[2, "Pr(>|t|)"], 2)
))
str(lmresults)
```

Output from this:

```
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ category  : Factor w/ 2 levels "stuff with a stronger correlation",..: 1 2
 $ slope.df$x: num  4.15 12.31
 $ pval      : num  3.7e-09 3.7e-01
```

Note that "slope" and "pval" are both numeric. However, if I do this:

```
lmresults2 <- ddply(data, "category", function(df) c(
      pval = signif(summary(lm(df$y ~ df$x))$coef[2, "Pr(>|t|)"], 2),
      slope = paste("slope =", signif(coef(lm(df$y ~ df$x))[2], 2))
))
str(lmresults2)
```

The output is:

```
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ category: Factor w/ 2 levels "stuff with a stronger correlation",..: 1 2
 $ pval    : chr  "3.7e-09" "0.37"
 $ slope   : chr  "slope = 4.1" "slope = 12"
```

I was expecting `slope` to be character, but suddenly `pval` is character, too!

Is this a bug within *plyr*? Is it converting the output to a matrix, which has to have the same class for all data? But if that's the case, why is the class of the object `lmresults2` still "data.frame"?

Comment: plyr != dplyr; this looks like the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a bug.  It's because you use `c()` in your anonymous functions. According to `help(c)`:

> *All arguments are coerced to a common type which is the type of the returned value,*
>
> ...
>
> *The output type is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression.*

Your first anonymous function concatenates two calls that both result in numerics, hence no issue.  But your second anonymous function concatenates a numeric created with `signif()` with a character created by `paste()`, hence giving a character result.

Perhaps you want `data.frame(pval = ..., slope = ...)` instead of `c()`. For a simpler look at what's happening, have a look at the result of `c(1, "a")`. Is it numeric or character?

Comment: @LauraS you want to use `data.frame(pval = ..., slope = ...)` as `ddply` expects a data.frame as output. A `list` will return an error.

Comment: Thanks @ChiPak. I don't use plyr very often.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. That makes perfect sense! Thank you!